# Get the size of file from AWS Cloudian Object Store

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, command-line-interface

I currently use AWS S3 to retrieve a whole text file from S3 using the following command:

```
aws --profile=cloudian --endpoint-url=https://s3-abc.abcstore.abc.net s3 cp s3://abc-store/STORE1/abc2/ABC/test_08.txt test.txt
```

How can I just get the file size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the size, use head object operation.

```
aws --profile=cloudian --endpoint-url=https://s3-abc.abcstore.abc.net s3api head-object --bucket abc-store --key STORE1/abc2/ABC/test_08.txt --query 'ContentLength'
```

Comment: @TinaJ `aws s3api head-object --bucket <bucket_name> --key <key_name> --query 'ContentLength'`

Comment: @TinaJ yes, it's in bytes